# Symfony Forms: how to map only one of the fields of an embedded Form-Type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to develop a form that will later be used as a base-form for specialized variants.
So it will have *inherit_data => true*. It is furthermore mapped to a base-data-class.

In this base-form I also use a custom form-type that has some fields. This is where I am currently stuck. I want to have only one of the fields of the custom inner form-type to map back to the actual base-form so the mapping to the base-data-class can be done correctly.

I will try to show this by some simplified classes that hopefully convey what I want:

```
class BaseFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('unproblematicProperty')
            ->add('myProblematicProperty', InnerFormType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'inherit_data' => true,
            'data_class' => BaseDataClass::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then some InnerFormType:

```
class InnerFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('shouldBeMappedToMyProblematicProperty')
            ->add('shouldntBeMapped1')
            ->add('shouldntBeMapped2')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
        ]);
    }
}
```

The goal is that the data-class can be instantiated correctly without me having to make parts of the
BaseFormType unmapped even though they hold actual data for the objects to be instantiated. I.e. I don't want to have part of the object hydration to be done by binding the form-type to the data-class and part of it manually in a controller.

So, how can I achieve a direct "backmapping" of the value from *shouldBeMappedToMyProblematicProperty* to *myProblematicProperty*?

If the question needs improvement or further information I will try my best to edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out, this can elegantly be achieved by implementing DataMapperInterface in the InnerFormType.

The contract is to implement two methods:

- mapDataToForms($viewData, iterable $forms)
- mapFormsToData(iterable $forms, &$viewData)

Remark that if you need to change the representation of your data (in my case for example wrapping strings into UnicodeStrings and vice-versa), that the DataMapper is *not* the place to do so.

To do this use DataTransformers (implement DataTransformerInterface).

Remark that on *get* the DataMapper's method *mapDataToForms* is called
before DataTransformers *transform* while on form-submit DataTransformer's *reverseTransform* is called before DataMapper's *mapFormsToData*.

See also: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_mappers.html

To get a better understanding of the inner ongoings I found enlightening to
*dd(...)* some of the involved vars at certain points in the flow as the documentation is somewhat lacking in this area in my opinion.